# Esc beeping on first channel

Tags: esc, flysky

I have a Flysky fai6s transmitter which I used to control my ESCs.  When I put the wires of the ESC on channel 1 of the receiver the ESC starts beeping, but on other three channels it works fine.
I have callibrated the esc then also on channel 1 beeping sound is coming from esc but other channels are working fine!!!

Comment: When you say "channel 1", do you mean the first set of plugs? It's possible you're plugging your ESC into the bind channel. Otherwise, all channels except throttle start centered - so you should center your throttle on boot and if that fixes things, then recalibrate while plugged into the correct channel

Answer (score 1):

A beeping ESC has probably gone into its programming mode. This is usually accessed by starting with the throttle up, but you'd have to check the ESC instructions for the exact sequence.

I'd guess that this means you need to reverse channel 1, so the ESC sees zero throttle when it is first plugged in.

You've probably thought of this already, but make sure the prop is not fitted when doing this sort of testing, as the motor can go to full power unexpectedly.